# netty: does connect listener called before channelRead()?

Tags: multithreading, netty

In fact, I have two questions:

- The listener would be definitely called, not matter the connect is canceled or timeout, correct? If so, then if it's canceled, the `isSuccess()` returns true or false?
- If the connection get data when connected, the `channelRead()` would be called after the listener get called, that is, they would not get called concurrently, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes it will always be called... when cancelled isSuccess() will return false.

2) Yes it will be called after the listener is called. As the listener and the channelRead(...) method will be called by the EventLoop of the Channel there is no concurrency going on.

Comment: Is it still true when I specify an `EventExecutor` for the handler to do `channelRead()`? The doc (https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/New-and-noteworthy-in-4.0#well-defined-thread-model) said the `The ChannelFutureListeners added to ChannelFuture are always invoked by the EventLoop thread assigned to the future's associated Channel.`, but the handler would be executed in other `EventExecutor`.

Comment: nope then it is not true anymore if the EventExecutor != EventLoop.